# Nuget Package both source and dlls

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I want to create a .Net class library and allow the users the option to either use the DLL or the C# source directly.

I know how to pack DLLs. I know how to pack [source only packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52885223/4126652) (although it doesn't work for SDK style libraries). But I don't know how to allow the users to chose one.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61675189/4126652) has no answers and suggests that setting a default value for `<IncludeAssets>` is not possible. So by default both will be included and might cause conflict ?

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42613389/4126652) suggests to create two multiple NuGet packages like `Foo` and `Foo.Sources`. But I don't know how to do that in a neat workflow for a single solution/project either.

Any suggestions/resources or even example packages would be helpful.